# Why there are three outputs in transaction of coinbase?

Tags: bitcoin

When I looked into the coinbase of BTC, I found there were three outputs in it.
one for miners to get reward of BTC.
ont for commitment.
but the last one, I don't know what it is.
[image: outputs of coinbase]

Comment: Please don't link to external sites unless you have put all of the salient details in your question first.

Comment: Also, can you explain what the programming part of your question is?

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: yes,i want write a software about mining BTC, I must know how to generate this data.

Comment: Can you please show your code and where you're stuck?